# Entity Framework Core: how to get table B which references with table A with 2 composite keys

Tags: entity-framework-core, composite-primary-key

I'm using EF Core 6 to map my database table to entity classes using DB first.

I have table `Conversation_Users` has a composite primary key made up of 2 columns, which reference 2 other entities (`Conversation`, `User`) described in C# shown here:

```cs
public class Conversation_Users
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long ConversationId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }  // entity C, nevermind on it

    public virtual User User { get; set; }  // entity D, nevermind on it
}
```

I have other table `Message` which has a reference with table `Conversation_Users` with 2 foreign keys

```cs
[Table("Message")]
public class Message
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ConversationId")]
    public long ConversationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public long SenderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReferenceMessageId")]
    public long ReferenceMessageId { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public virtual Message ReferenceMessage { get; set; }  // refer to itself

    public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }  // entity C, nevermind on it

    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }  // entity D, nevermind on it
}
```

From an instance of entity `Message` (message), how can I get the value `Name` property in entity `Conversation_Users`?

Comment: Tip, remove A, B, C from question and use real model class names. It is all navigation properties that exists in your classes?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv edited as you want

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via LINQ query.

```cs
// input parameters
var messageId = ...

var query = 
    from m in context.Messages
    where m.Id == messageId
    join cu in context.Conversation_Users on 
       new { m.ConversationId, UserId = m.SenderId } equals 
       new { cu.ConversationId, cu.UserId }
    select cu.Name;

var conversationName = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Anyway, it is suspicious Model design, which should contain approperiate navigation properties. Looks like it is many-to-many relationship.

Comment: is there anyway to use linq command like this
`message.Conversation_User.Name`. I prefer this one

Comment: because it's being used in LINQ select statement (`.Select(s => new ...)`)

Comment: Show there three model classes and their mapping.

Comment: I showed it on my question. what do you mean 3 model classes?

Comment: `Conversation` ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it isn't important. it's just another entity with mapped successfully to `Message`. I can call `message.Conversation.Name` on it. If you want me to show the `Conversation` model, you can image it's a class with `Id` is key and `Name` is string, and so is `User`, same as `Conversation`